# Returning a list opens a blank page with requested values

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, entity-framework-4

In my controller I have a function to get the roles that belong to a user. 
This function is using .GetRolesAsync() and is returning an IList.
In the browser the user can submit a name, and see the roles for a user. 
This however returns my list in a blank page. [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HiaCq.png)

```
Controller :     
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<IList<string>> GetRoles(UserRoleViewModel model) 
    {
        ApplicationUser user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);
        if(user != null)
        {
            model.GetRoles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
        }
        return model.GetRoles;
    }
```

How can I return this list to my ViewModel without opening a blank page so I can call this from my view ?

```
ViewModel :
public class UserRoleViewModel
{
    public List<SelectListItem> Roles { get; set; }
    public IList<string> GetRoles { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set;}
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string CurrentPassword { get; set; }
    public string NewPassword { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You want to return to View or assign roles to ViewModel?

Comment: Return to the same view and display the roles.

Comment: Pls check my answer below. Or you can create a List<string> property in your view model and set in the controller and return it.

Comment: That's what I already did, I posted my ViewModel as well.

Comment: Which view you want to return from this method? You should return view not Model.

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, you are getting the blank page because , when the below method get executes,

**Existing code :**

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<IList<string>> GetRoles(UserRoleViewModel model) 
    {
        ApplicationUser user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);
        if(user != null)
        {
            model.GetRoles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
        }
        return model.GetRoles;
    }
```

It return just result of list and doesn't return any actionresult to retain in the same view

**Solution :**

Make the returntype of the method like below

**Replaced code :**

```
[HttpPost]
    public  async Task<ActionResult> GetRoles(UserRoleViewModel model) 
    {
        ApplicationUser user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);
        if(user != null)
        {
            model.GetRoles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
        }
        return view("viewname")  
      //Note: here viewname can be the same view ,where this post method was 
       // called if you dont want to create new view
    }
```

And  specify the view name of which you called this post method, if you dont want to create a new view.

So that it wont give  a blank page for the user , when it is called.

Hope the above information was useful , kindly let me know your thoughts or feedbacks

Thanks

Karthik